# Has anyone attempted a master clock sync implementation with AudioKit?

Tags: audiokit

The `AKMIDITempoListener` implements a `midiClockMasterEnabled` method that tells you if/when you can become the MIDI master clock, but there aren't any examples of how one might implement a MIDI master clock in AudioKit (e.g. using `AKSequencer` as the master).

Has anyone attempted this?

I'm thinking that I would probably need to add a callback instrument track that sends MIDI timing clock data to destinations 24 times per beat (per MIDI spec), or something like that. I'm open to any & all suggestions here.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

midiClockMasterEnabled tells you when you can become the master.  There is no implementation of generating clocks at the moment.